# JQAssistant - is it possible to query for the value of annotation attributes?

Tags: java, jqassistant

We are thinking about doing some JQAssistant concepts/rules based on the values of annotation attributes.

Can these values be queried and evaluated with JQAssistant?

Example: Find all classes that have methods that are annotated with

```
@javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query returns all types annotated by `@TransactionAttribute` and the value:

`MATCH
  (t:Type)-[:ANNOTATED_BY]->(txAttribute)-[:OF_TYPE]->(:Type{fqn:"javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute"}),
  (txAttribute)-[:HAS]->(:Value{name:"value"})-[:IS]->(txAttributeType:Field)
RETURN
  t.fqn, txAttributeType.signature`

The result looks like this:

`"your.project.a.impl.ServiceAImpl"  "javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType REQUIRES_NEW"`

The returned value is the signature of the according field declared in the enum type `TransactionAttributeType`.

Comment: Theres also a tutorial about annotations and values available on the project's website, see https://101.jqassistant.org/annotations-single/